# How to print multiples of a given variable in java?

Tags: java, variables, math, multiplication

There are 3 numbers that are given to the user.  These three numbers define the multiple, and the range.  For example if these three numbers are (3, 6 , 17) the program should print 6,9,12,15. The first number is the base multiple and the second and third numbers are the lowest and the highest numbers (the range).  I also know that I do not need all the import statements that I have.

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to continue.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class printMultiplesOf{
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1, num2, num3;

        System.out.println("Enter the 1st number");
        num1 = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the 2nd number");
        num2 = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the 3rd number");
        num3 = reader.nextInt();

        printMultiplesOf(num1, num2, num3);
    }

    public static void printMultiplesOf(int num1, int num2, int num3){
        int start = num2
        int end = num3
        for (int i = num1; i <= num1; i++){
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = num1; i <= num1;` <-- read this again

Comment: Thank you it now works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is finding the loop's start and end point. The start point needs to the first number divisible by `num1` equal or larger than `num2`. You can find it by dividing `num2/num1` using floating-point division, `ceil` the result and multiply it back by `num1`. Similarly, the loop's end point should be the largest number divisible by `num1` which is less than or equal to `num3`. You can find it by dividing `num3/num1` using integer division (which would effectively `floor` the result and then multiplying it back again by `num1`. From there on, it's just a matter of looping in steps the size of `num1`. E.g.:

```
public static void printMultiplesOf(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int start = ((int) Math.ceil((double) num2 / num1)) * num1;
    int end = (num3 / num1) * num1;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i+= num1) {
        System.out.println (i + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the numbers in the range, and check if it's a multiple.

```
 public static void printMultiplesOf(int num1, int num2, int num3) {

        for(int i=num2; i<= num3; i++){
            if(i % num1 == 0)
                System.out.print(i +" ");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your function. You simply add your num1 to i each time loop is executed.
I tried it and it is working ;)

```
 public static void printMultiplesOf(int num1, int num2, int num3){
          int multi = num1;
          int start = num2;
          int end = num3;

          for (int i = start; i <= end; i += multi){
               System.out.println(i + " ");
          }
    }
```